# Convert MacAddress to IPv6 Link Local in Java

Tags: java, mac-address, link-local

I need to convert a Mac Address into an `IPv6 Link` Local address.
This `link-local IPv6` is infered from the `NIC’s` mac address. 
The conversion procedure is as given below.

1. take the mac address: for example `52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f`
2. throw ff:fe in the middle: `52:74:f2:ff:fe:b1:a8:7f`
3. reformat to IPv6 notation `5274:f2ff:feb1:a87f`
4. convert the first octet from hexadecimal to binary: `52 -> 01010010`
5. invert the bit at index 6 (counting from 0): `01010010 -> 01010000`
6. convert octet back to hexadecimal: `01010000 -> 50`
7. replace first octet with newly calculated one: `5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f`
8. prepend the link-local prefix: `fe80::5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f`

This seems to be a lot of specific string manipulation and conversion between number systems.
I was looking for a utility class in Java which could help me do the same in a more efficient manner.
I see that Java has methods in `InetAddress` to determine if the address in question is a link local.

Comment: Implements your own builder of `Inet6Address` and use [Inet6Address#isLinkLocalAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#isLinkLocalAddress--) ?

Comment: But we will still need to do splitting,replacement,re-joining , grouping , conversion and bit inversion. It seems like a lot of logic.
I am surprised that there is no utility for the same.

Comment: You have enhanced utilities for String manipulation like `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) has methods to do this.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Here is sample code using your example MAC address 52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f

```java
   String str = "52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f";
   try {
      MACAddress mac = new MACAddressString(str).toAddress();
      IPv6Address linkLocal = mac.toLinkLocalIPv6();
      System.out.println("converted " + mac + " to IPv6 link local " + linkLocal);
   } catch(AddressStringException e) {
      // handle invalid address string here
   }
```

Output is:

```
converted 52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f to IPv6 link local fe80::5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f
```

More [examples](https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress/wiki/Code-Examples#convert-tofrom-ipv6-address-fromto-mac-address) are in the wiki.

Comment: Nice contribution, your library is robust and well-tested. I upvoted and I think it should be the accepted answer instead of trying to reinvent the wheel with the draft I provided.